# Regexp to extract binary from a string

Tags: regex, string, binary, extract

Is it possible to have string and extract the binary value from it and additionally only get the last binary digit from the value:

```
String = FCW2026P4F6
```

this would output in binary:

```
01000110 01000011 01010111 00110010 00110000 00110010 00110110 01010000 00110100 01000110 00110110
```

Now I would actually only need the last binary digit 0 from this.
Any way this can be done by pure regexp?

Thanks.

Have not tried anything yet as I don't think this is doable.

Comment: Are you trying to convert each character to its ASCII value and then to binary? You can use a regexp to extract `FCW2026P4F6` from `String = FCW2026P4F6`, but you'll need other code to convert to binary.

Comment: ["*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.*"](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Comment: @InSync, a wise man from the east once said, "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions'." Those in attendance  were amazed and delighted when the man then proceeded to demonstrate the power and elegance of those expressions".

Comment: @CarySwoveland What do you mean by that? I was just telling OP not to try using nothing but regex to do a binary conversion.

Comment: @InSync, lest some readers interpret that quote (without reading the text at the link) as meaning that the use of regular expressions should be avoided I merely wanted to point out they have their place. I did not mean to imply that you held that belief--you clearly do not--though some readers may have incorrectly thought you did whether I made my comment or not.  I have the greatest respect and admiration for your contributions to SO.  I shared your intent, incidentally, until I read Sam's very clever answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but only under certain conditions. If you've got the possibility to use [PCRE2](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replaceconditional.html#:%7E:text=PCRE2%20Replacement%20String%20Conditional,name%3A%2Bmatched%3Aunmatched%7D.), you can use an expression like this:

```
(.*[BDFHJLNPRTVXZ02468]$)|(.*[ACEGIKMOQSUWY13579]$)
```

and replace with

```
${1:+0:1}
```

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/uYCB86/2

The expression is split into two parts. The first are all the even numbered characters and the second is the odd ones. Add characters as needed. They are grouped with an *or* in between like this `(ending with even character)|(ending with odd character)`.
The replacement says "if group one matches, replace with 0, otherwise 1".

<sub><sub>Mandatory message: Don't use regex for this.</sub></sub>

Comment: This is very cool! You may wish to include [this link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replaceconditional.html#:~:text=PCRE2%20Replacement%20String%20Conditional,name%3A%2Bmatched%3Aunmatched%7D.) to documentation of this feature of PCRE2, in which case I'll delete this comment. Note "certain conditions" is is vague. If you are referring only to the opportunity to use PCRE2 you should simply remove the first sentence.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, link added. Thanks! There are other variants that allow for conditional replacements, albeit rare.

Answer (score 1):

Though less satisfying than ones that use a regular expression to match strings directly, if you append `"01"` to each string you can match the resulting string with the regular expression

```
(?<=[BDFHJLNPRTVXZ02468])0(?=1$)|(?<=[ACEGIKMOQSUWY13579]0)1$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qnKhP4/1)

This works with many languages, including PHP, Perl, R, Javascript, Python, Ruby and .NET.

The above regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<=                     # begin positive lookbehind
  [BDFHJLNPRTVXZ02468]   # match one character in character class
)                        # end positive lookbehind
0                        # match "0"
(?=                      # begin positive lookahead
  1                      # match "1"
  $                      # match end of string
)                        # end positive lookahead
|                        # or
(?<=                     # begin positive lookbehind
  [ACEGIKMOQSUWY13579]   # match one character in character class
  0                      # match "0"
)                        # end positive lookbehind
1                        # match "1"
$                        # assert match is at end of string
```

My answer was inspired by @Sam's excellent solution.